# Grails Date constructor and parsing Dates

Tags: java, excel, date, grails

I have an excel spreadsheet in which dates are written like this: 6/10/2012. Now, Grails is reading them in using the excel import plugin and when I ask it to print them its prints them as: 2012-06-10. The date is coming into my service in the form of a map like

```
map: [name: name, date: date, price: price]
```

I tried to do:

```
Date date = Date(map.date)
```

and of course I got an error.

```
2012-06-10
ERROR: Record could not be saved!
org.grails.datastore.mapping.validation.ValidationErrors: 2 errors
Field error in object 'com.twc.fatcaone.Record' on field 'date': rejected value [null]; codes            [com.twc.fatcaone.Record.date.nullable.error.com.twc.fatcaone.Record.date,com.twc.fatcaone.Record.da
```

I see that some of the java.util.Date constructors are deprecated so I was hesitant to use them but I was also wondering whats the cleanest way to parse into the map to grab the date and form a Date object from it?

Comment: `Date.parse( 'MM/dd/yyyy', map.date )` ?

Comment: @dmahapatro Thanks for your response. I tried that as well as 'yyyy-dd-MM' but I got this in both cases:  Error |
2014-06-10 20:57:15,629 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [POST] /FatcaOne_0/customer/upload
No signature of method: static java.util.Date.parse() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.joda.time.LocalDate) values: [yyyy-MM-dd, 2012-06-10]

Comment: It has to be String format as first parameter and String date as the second. Since you are using Joda time, `toDate()` on `LocalDate` should be sufficient. `map.date.toDate()` should give a `java.util.Date`, no need of parsing anymore. Otherwise, if you still want to use `Date.parse` then the second parameter has to be a String as in `map.date.toString()`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yup, absolutely right. I used toDate() and no more parsing needed. Thank you.

Comment: @dmahapatro Post your comment as an answer so this question can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be a String `format` as first parameter and a String `date` as the second.

Since you are using Joda time, `toDate()` on `LocalDate` should be sufficient. `map.date.toDate()` should give a `java.util.Date`, no need to parse anymore.

Otherwise, if you still want to use `Date.parse` then the second parameter has to be a String as in `map.date.toString()`.